# parse a Json string with Newtonsoft

Tags: .net, json, vb.net

I have a JSON object that I store in a database that is created by
        var data = JSON.stringify($('#frm').serializeArray());  I want to call it and use Newtonsoft.json to parse it out into it's parts.  My totally convoluted VB.Net code is (Dont pick on me I know it is a hack)

```
     Dim reader As JsonTextReader = New JsonTextReader(New StringReader(TextBox1.Text))
    Dim firstname As String = ""
    Dim middleInitial As String = ""
    Dim lastName As String = ""


    While (reader.Read())

        Select Case reader.Value
            Case "disFirst"
                reader.Read()
                reader.Read()
                firstname = reader.Value
            Case "disMiddle"
                reader.Read()
                reader.Read()
                middleInitial = reader.Value
            Case "disLast"
                reader.Read()
                reader.Read()
                lastName = reader.Value
        End Select
    End While

    MessageBox.Show(firstname + " " + middleinitial + " " + lastName)
```

but it works.  I 100% know that there are MUCH better ways so if someone can point me in the right VB.Net direction that would be great.  My Json string is

```
    [{"name":"disFirst","value":"Robert"},{"name":"disMiddle","value":"S"},{"name":"disLast","value":"Smith"},{"name":"disSuffix","value":""},{"name":"disEmail","value":"Smith@xxxxxxx.edu, 12345@zzzzz.edu"},{"name":"disAffiliations","value":"Arizona\r\nXXXX"},{"name":"disPMIDlist","value":""},{"name":"disThreshholdFactor","value":""}]
```

Comment: That code is not really parsing it (`JObject.Parse(jstr)`).  That seems like it should deserialize to an array pretty easily.  Seems a bad structure though since the names arent related to each other.  "Robert" is not linked or related to "Smith"

Comment: I've gotten closer.  the structure I can't control since it is a standard jQuery serialize of a form.  What I've gotten to is

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to add code in the add comment

Comment: While (reader.Read())
            If reader.TokenType = JsonToken.StartObject Then
                Dim obj As JObject = JObject.Load(reader)

Comment: then   If obj("name") = "disFirst" Then
                    firstname = obj("value")
                End If

Comment: my javascript ajax call is   var obj = JSON.parse(data.d); and then      var item1 = obj[0].value;
                      var item2 = obj[1].value;
                      var item3 = obj[2].value;
                      var item4 = obj[3].value;

Comment: What am I supposed to do with that?  The Q shows the data coming from a textbox; the answer shows how to process that.  Since you cant change the json, not sure what thats for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That json is more that a little wonky.  It appears to be describing an entity, but rather than an object with firstname, lastname etc it is just a set of name pairs. As long as there is just one entity there, I guess it could work.

This will deserialize the json to an array of name pairs:

```
Public Class NameValuePair
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property value As String
End Class
```

Then to deserialize:

```
Dim jstr = from whereever
Dim myNVPs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of NameValuePair())(jstr)
```

The `name` will contain those awful keys like `disLast` and `value` will be the related data.  As an array you can loop thru it to get the data.

Comment: perfect- works like a charm.  the ugly names like disFirst and disLast are strange because the dis identifies the form that they are on. There are other places in the application that call for first name and last name etc. the the JSON is created automatically by JSON.stringify($('#frm').serializeArray()); using the name of the input element

Comment: It is more common for those to come back already as some sort of unified object like Person {FIrst, Last, Middle, Gender, BirthDate...etc} then you would not have to piece it together and could pass more than one at a time if needed.  Glad it worked